# How delete feature from layer using Gdal binding java

Tags: gdal, java

I am trying delete one feature from layer using GDAL in java https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava

But nothing happens.

> ```
>     ogr.RegisterAll();
>     Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
>     DataSource ds = driver.Open(shape,1);
> ```

```
    Layer layer = ds.GetLayer(0);
    System.out.println(layer.GetFeatureCount());

    layer.DeleteFeature(0);
    ds.SyncToDisk();
```

> 

Anyone know what the problem is?
I tried too use layer.StartTransaction(); and layer.CommitTransaction();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950627/how-to-delete-feature-from-shapefile-using-gdal-c